# Creating a large ground texture for mobile

Tags: textures, mobile, mesh

Does anyone has any insight on creating / texturing a large mesh that will be used for a mobile game's level map?

Specifically, I was wondering how games like Vainglory achieve this.

I am familiar with the idea of splat maps, however this is where my knowledge of the subject ends...

Is the use of splats on mobile a good solution? Should the mesh be broken down into small sections which are UV'd and textured separately? Neither of these things?

Answer (score 2):

You'll generally want to break up the mesh (and the textures for the mesh) into uniform, grid-like chunks at runtime. You can *author* the mesh as one giant terrain if that's more comfortable for you. But you'll want to have some process that splits it up as you import it into your game.

This will let you cull parts of the terrain that are far offscreen (and thus don't need to be rendered), as well as allow you to stream the terrain in and out of memory as the players move around on it in order to fit within your memory budgets.

Texture splatting is, in this case, mostly irrelevant. It's a good technique to add detail and richness to the appearance of the terrain, but it's not really an optimization technique related to fitting a large map into memory.